# How to have Creative Tim Angular Material Pro render regions on JVectorMap?

Tags: angular, typescript, jvectormap

I'm trying to display coloured regions on the JVectorMap of the world included in the Creative Tim Angular Material Pro page.

I have found some examples on StackOverflow to colour regions using standard `<script>` tags, or creating a simple single page, but the examples don't work when introduced into the Creative Tim Angular Material Pro project.  In each case the map renders as per out of the box (hover, onClick events, etc all working) **but no colouring of the regions**.

Can someone who has done this successfully please describe how they got this working?
- Using the default map, or importing the Miller projection
- Specific configuration objects (I've seen examples of providing region values, or explicit colours per region)
- Any events or ElementRefs I might need

I am adding region data to the map that is found on the Creative Tim project file:

```
src/app/dashboard/dashboard
```

from the dashboard.component.ts (lines #164 - 187):

```
  $('#worldMap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: '#818181',
    borderOpacity: 0.25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: '#b3b3b3',
    enableZoom: true,
    hoverColor: '#eee',
    hoverOpacity: null,
    normalizeFunction: 'linear',
    scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
    selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
    selectedRegions: null,
    showTooltip: true,
    onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
      const message = 'You clicked "'
        + region
        + '" which has the code: '
        + code.toUpperCase();

      alert(message);
    }
  });
}
```

changing the JVectorMap initialisation to the following:

```
$('#worldMap').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_en',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderColor: '#818181',
  borderOpacity: 0.25,
  borderWidth: 1,
  color: '#b3b3b3',
  enableZoom: true,
  hoverColor: '#eee',
  hoverOpacity: null,
  normalizeFunction: 'linear',
  scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
  selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
  selectedRegions: null,
  showTooltip: true,
  series: {
    regions: [{
      scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
      values: {
        'AU': 1219.72,
        'BR': 2023.53,
        'DE': 3305.9,
        'RO': 158.39,
        'GB': 2258.57,
        'US': 14624.18
      },
      attribute: 'fill'  // I saw this added in a different example but doesn't hurt or help here
    }]
  }
});
```

**Three observations I've made, tried, but that didn't succeed:**

**Observation 1-**
I found anexample of how to create the series data with Javascript that calls a `.setValues()` method for the series.  (See http://jvectormap.com/examples/random-colors/)

```
const map = $('#worldMap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
map.series.regions[0].setValues(this.seriesData);
```

When I try this, I get and error that `setValues()` does not exist on the object.

**Observation 2-**
All of the examples I've found that do work use the Miller projection vector map available from the JVectorMap website.  I tried to get this working in case this was the cause but with the following results:
- I can get the 'world-mill-en' map to render correctly (you can see the width difference as proof)
- On region hover, there is a JQuery error that I can't work out.
- I tried the map file from JVectorMap, and also from various examples but all gave the same JQuery error.
- Some of the maps were named 'world-mill' where the JVectorMap download was 'world-mill-en'

**Observation 3-**
Interogating the map object shows that there is region series data on the map object in:

```
canvas/params/series/regions[0]
```

See:

[image]

This is not displaying any change on the map (the map renders the same as out of the box).

Am I missing firing an event?  Is Creative Tim CSS overriding the region display?  Seems strange for a product they're embedding in their product.

Any tips or insight into what I'm missing greatly appreciated.  Thanks

PS - Here's the new image after adding min/max

[image]

Comment: I don't see the *min* and *max* values for the `scale`, they should be set automatically by jVectorMap. Try to set both those params by yourself, here is the documentation: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-dataseries/ - hard to guess, because I believe the demo page itself is not working.

Comment: Hi @Deblocker, thanks for having a look and help.  I tried setting the max/min values.  On the initial chart creation I get a syntax error saying min/max are not valid settings for the region object.  I can set them after initialisation using exactly the same series object (maybe missing Typescipt types?).  They are on the object (see blue rectangle) but there are odd array of sorts (see red oval) that looks like a getter being executed being created as an array property?

Answer (score 0):

Happy days!!

@Chelaruc from the Create Tim team came to the rescue!  See:

https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-angular/issues/348

There are two issues here:

1) The array of coloured regions is being passed directly to the "values" property of JVectorMap (instead of as a property of the "regions" property group).

E.g.:

```
 const sample_data = {
  'us': '53.23',
  'de': '20.43',
  'au': '10.35',
  'gb': '7.87',
  'ro': '5.94',
  'br': '4.34'};

  $('#worldMap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor:' #fff',
        color: '#ffffff',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        selectedColor: '#666666',
        enableZoom: false,
        showTooltip: true,
        values: sample_data,
        scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
  });
```

I've asked then how to add a marker series of values but haven't gotten a reply yet.  No reason was given as to the variation on syntax in the Creative Tim template.

2) The country code values MUST be in lower case.  I'm assuming this is because the JQuery on the object is case sensitive (not having used JQuery much at all).

Thanks Creative Tim ... I had resorted to Googles GeoMap but happy to re implement the JVectorMap (Please provide examples for Markers though).